# How to create dynamic dataset names in Procedures

Tags: sas

Can someone help me with the below problem?

```
Proc transpose data=x.output1 out=work.var1;
run;
```

In the above procedure,if I want to transpose **N-number** of datasets and create **N-number** of output datasets, how can I make this dynamic?

Answer (score 1):

Try a do loop in a macro.

```
%macro createData(n);

 %do i=1 %to &n;
    Proc transpose data=x.output&i out=work.var&i;
    run;
 %end;
%mend;

%createdata(10);
```

This will read 10 datasets x.output1 to x.output10 and create work.var1 to work.var10